# Как находить данные обьекты в arraylist по id, изза хэша ничего не получается

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

```
package Model;

import Model.Exceptions.NoMoneyEX;
import Model.Exceptions.NrAccountEX;
import Model.ObserverPattern.Observable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;


public class Bank implements BankingOperations, Observable {

    private BankAccount bankAccount;


    private ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts;


    public Bank() {
        accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    }



    public void addAccount(BankAccount e) throws NrAccountEX {
        if (accounts.equals(e)){
            throw new NrAccountEX("Account z takim id juz istieje");
        } else{
            accounts.add(e);
            System.out.println("Konto: " + e + " Zostało dodane!");
        }
    }


    public void wyswietlListe(){
          for (int i = 0; i<accounts.size(); i++){
              System.out.println(accounts.get(i));
          }
          System.out.println(accounts);
    }



    @Override
    public void deposit(int nrAccount, double amount)throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
                if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccount)) {
                    accounts.get(i).deposit(amount);
                    System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                    if (amount >= 10000) {
                        //+raport
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void withdraw(int nrAccount, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
         if (amount < 0){
             throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
         }else {
             for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
                 if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccount)) {
                     if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() < amount){
                         throw new NoMoneyEX("Twój balance " + accounts.get(i).getBalance()+ "jest mniejszy od kwoty" + amount + "Podaj mniejszą kwotę");
                     }else if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() >= amount) {
                         accounts.get(i).withdraw(amount);
                         System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało obciazone o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                     }
                     if (amount >= 10000) {
                         //+raport
                     }
                 } else {
                     throw new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta");
                 }
             }
         }

    }

    @Override
    public void transfer(int nrAccountFrom, int nrAccountTO, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
        if (amount <0){
            throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
        }else {
            for (int i = 0; i<accounts.size(); i++){
                if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccountFrom) == true){
                    if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() < amount){
                        throw new NoMoneyEX("Saldo twojego konta nie pozwala zrobic przelew: balance " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                    }else if (accounts.get(i).getBalance() >= amount){
                    for (int j = 0; j < accounts.size(); j++) {
                        if (accounts.get(j).equals(nrAccountTO)) {
                            accounts.get(i).withdraw(amount);
                            accounts.get(j).deposit(amount);
                            System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccountFrom + " zostało obciazone o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                            System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccountTO + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + accounts.get(i).getBalance());
                            if (amount >= 10000){
                                //+raport
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new NrAccountEX("Konto na kture chcesz zrobic przelew nie istnieje, podaj prawidlowy numer");
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }else {
                    throw new NrAccountEX("Konto z kturego chcesz zrobic przelew nie istnieje, podaj prawidlowy numer");
                }

            }
        }


         }




    }
```

Comment: Вот это `accounts.equals(e)` - никогда не будет `true`. Наверное, вы имели в виду что-то такое: `accounts.contains(e)`. Последнее же будет работать только если вы переопределите equals метод в `BankAccount` с прописанным корректным сравнением объектов. Наверное, их можно/нужно просто по ID сравнивать.

Comment: я переопределил в классе BankAccount метод equals и поставил сравнение по id, задача в том, чтобы я мог сравнивать и находить нужные обьекты с листы по id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поиска банковского счёта по его номеру в списке следует определить отдельный метод.  Предположим, что номер счёта возвращается геттером `BankAccount::getAccountId`, тогда:

```java
// обычный цикл
public boolean hasAccount(BankAccount account) {
    for (BankAccount ba : accounts) {
        if (ba.getAccountId() == account.getAccountId()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Stream API: anyMatch
public boolean hasAccountStream(BankAccount account) {
    return accounts.stream().anyMatch(ba -> ba.getAccountId() == account.getAccountId());       
}
```

Затем нужно вызвать данный метод из метода `addAccount`:

```java
public void addAccount(BankAccount e) throws NrAccountEX {
    if (hasAccount(e)) {
        throw new NrAccountEX("Account z takim id juz istieje");
    } 
    accounts.add(e);
    System.out.println("Konto: " + e + " Zostało dodane!");
}
```

---

Однако следует заметить, что хранение списка счетов данным образом будет не слишком эффективным, и гораздо лучше было бы реализовать хэш-таблицу с ключом - номером счёта, тогда поиск счетов будет выполняться с константной сложностью O(1) без ненужных циклов:

```java
public class Bank implements BankingOperations, Observable {
    private Map<Integer, BankAccount> accounts;

    public Bank() {
        accounts = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addAccount(BankAccount account) throws NrAccountEX {
        if (accounts.containsKey(account.getAccountId())) {
            throw new NrAccountEX("Account z takim id juz istieje");
        }
        accounts.put(account.getAccountId(), account);
    }

    @Override
    public void deposit(int nrAccount, double amount) throws NrAccountEX, NoMoneyEX {
        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new NoMoneyEX("Kwota musi byc większa od 0!!!!");
        }
        // найти счёт по его номеру
        BankAccount account = accounts.get(nrAccount);

        if (null == account) {
            throw new NrAccountEX("podaleś nieistniejący numer konta");
        }
        account.deposit(amount);
        System.out.println("Konto numeru: " + nrAccount + " zostało dołądowane o kwote: " + amount + " ,stan konta: " + account.getBalance());
        if (amount >= 10000) {
            //+raport
        }
    }
//...
// другие методы с аналогичным поиском счета/счетов по номеру
}
```

Comment: спасибо) Добавление аккаунтов в листу работает, мне еще нужно в методах депозит, снятие и перевод находить аккаунты по id c листы(в этом задании нужно использовать arraylist а не хэш таблицу), но метод на вход получает номер счета и сумму а не bankAccount. Я пытался находить по данному id в листе при помощи for (int i = 0; i<accounts.size(); i++){
                if (accounts.get(i).equals(nrAccountFrom) == true), но это не работает, какую методу сделать для этой задачи?

Comment: `поиск счетов будет выполняться с константной сложностью O(1) без ненужных циклов` это будет верно только в случае, если не будет коллизий приведения hashCode от ID аккаунта к числу от 0 до 15. Т.е, в лучшем случае максимум для 16 аккаунтов. В худшем случае прироста скорости вообще не будет - сложность будет O(n). Средняя сложность же будет около O(log(n))

Comment: _если не будет коллизий приведения hashCode от ID аккаунта к числу от 0 до 15_ А откуда взялись такие ограничения??  И каким образом должны возникнуть коллизии, если в качестве ключа используется `int` / `Integer` номер счёта, и ключи по логике являются уникальными (при попытке добавить счет с неуникальным ключом выбраывается исключение)?